# Console arkanoid in C

Tags: beginner, c, game, console, posix

On an Internet forum a person came with their homework, to write Arkanoid in a console - it seemed they wanted someone to do their homework for them so I did not respond. However, I found the task interesting, especially when I broadened the scope of the assignment - so I wrote such arkanoid for my own entertainment. However, I don't really know C coding patterns so I'd be interested to know what more experienced devs think about my code.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>

const short brick_color = 1;
const short other_color = 2;

#define board_y_size 21
#define board_x_size 78

typedef enum { EMPTY, BRICK, BALL } content;
typedef struct
{
  unsigned lv;
  unsigned balls_left;
  bool running;
  content board[board_y_size][board_x_size];
  int ball_y, ball_x;
  int racket_pos;
  int delta_y, delta_x;
  unsigned score;
} game_data;

void init_new_level(game_data* gd)
{
  gd->lv++;
  if(gd->lv % 3 == 0)
    gd->balls_left++;
  gd->running = false;
  gd->racket_pos = 39;

  for(int y = 0; y < board_y_size; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < board_x_size; x++)
      gd->board[y][x] = EMPTY;
  for(int y = 2; y < board_y_size - 4; y++)
    for(int x = 2; x < board_x_size - 2; x++)
      gd->board[y][x] = BRICK;
  gd->ball_y = board_y_size-1;
  gd->ball_x = gd->racket_pos;
  gd->board[gd->ball_y][gd->ball_x] = BALL;
}

void advance_ball(game_data* gd, int new_y, int new_x)
{
  gd->board[gd->ball_y][gd->ball_x] = EMPTY;
  gd->board[new_y][new_x] = BALL;
  gd->ball_y = new_y;
  gd->ball_x = new_x;
}

void recover_from_miss(game_data* gd)
{
  gd->racket_pos = 39;

ball_found:
  advance_ball(gd, board_y_size-1, gd->racket_pos);
}

int start_level(game_data* gd, int input)
{
  gd->delta_y = -1;
  if(input == KEY_LEFT)
    gd->delta_x = -1;
  else
    gd->delta_x = 1;

  gd->running = true;

  return (int)round(1000.0/pow(1.25, gd->lv-1));
}

void y_bounce(game_data* gd)
{
  gd->delta_y *= -1;
}

void x_bounce(game_data* gd)
{
  gd->delta_x *= -1;
}

void flip(game_data* gd)
{
  y_bounce(gd);
  x_bounce(gd);
}

void crush_bricks(game_data* gd, int y, int x)
{
  if(y >= 0 && y < board_y_size && x >= 0 && x < board_x_size &&
     gd->board[y][x] == BRICK)
  {
    gd->board[y][x] = EMPTY;
    gd->score++;
  }
}

bool is_out_of_board(int y)
{
  return y >= board_y_size;
}

bool is_blocked(game_data* gd, int y, int x)
{
  if(y < 0 || x < 0 || x >= board_x_size)
    return true;

  return gd->board[y][x] == BRICK;
}

bool normal_move(game_data* gd)
{
  int old_y = gd->ball_y, old_x = gd->ball_x;
  int new_y = old_y + gd->delta_y;
  int new_x = old_x + gd->delta_x;
  if(is_out_of_board(new_y))
  {
    gd->running = false;
    gd->balls_left--;
    return false;
  }

  else
  {
    int actual_new_x = new_x, actual_new_y = new_y;

    if(is_blocked(gd, old_y, new_x) && is_blocked(gd, new_y, old_x) ||
       is_blocked(gd, new_y, new_x) &&
         !is_blocked(gd, old_y, new_x) && !is_blocked(gd, new_y, old_x))
    {
      flip(gd);
      actual_new_x = old_x;
      actual_new_y = old_y;
    }

    else if(is_blocked(gd, old_y, new_x))
    {
      actual_new_x = old_x;
      x_bounce(gd);
    }
    else if(is_blocked(gd, new_y, old_x))
    {
      actual_new_y = old_y;
      y_bounce(gd);
    }

    advance_ball(gd, actual_new_y, actual_new_x);

    crush_bricks(gd, old_y, new_x);
    crush_bricks(gd, new_y, old_x);
    crush_bricks(gd, new_y, new_x);
  }

  return true;
}

bool collide_with_racket(game_data* gd)
{
  int old_y = gd->ball_y, old_x = gd->ball_x;
  int new_y = old_y + gd->delta_y;
  int new_x = old_x + gd->delta_x;

  if(old_y != board_y_size-1 || new_y != board_y_size)
    return false;

  if(new_x == gd->racket_pos-1 || new_x == gd->racket_pos-2 && gd->delta_x < 0)
  {
    y_bounce(gd);
    new_x = gd->racket_pos+1;
    gd->delta_x = 1;
    new_y = old_y-1;
    advance_ball(gd, new_y, new_x);
    return true;
  }
  else if(new_x == gd->racket_pos+1 || new_x == gd->racket_pos + 2 && gd->delta_x > 0)
  {
    y_bounce(gd);
    new_x = gd->racket_pos-1;
    gd->delta_x = -1;
    new_y = old_y-1;
    advance_ball(gd, new_y, new_x);
    return true;
  }
  else if(new_x == gd->racket_pos)
  {
    y_bounce(gd);
    new_x += gd->delta_x;
    new_y = old_y-1;
    advance_ball(gd, new_y, new_x);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

bool no_bricks_left(game_data* gd)
{
  for(int y = 0; y < board_y_size; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < board_x_size; x++)
      if(gd->board[y][x] == BRICK)
        return false;
  gd->running = false;
  return true;
}

bool process_turn(game_data* gd)
{
  if(!collide_with_racket(gd))
  {
    if(!normal_move(gd))
      return false;
    return no_bricks_left(gd);
  }
  return false;
}

void move_racket(game_data* gd, int racket_move)
{
  if(gd->racket_pos + racket_move >= 1 &&
     gd->racket_pos + racket_move < board_x_size-1)
  {
    gd->racket_pos+=racket_move;
  }
}

void print_game_data(game_data const* gd)
{
  for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++) 
  {
    mvaddch(0, x, ' ');
    mvaddch(23, x, ' ');
  }

  mvprintw(0, 3, "Lv: %u", gd->lv);
  mvprintw(0, 65, "Balls: %u", gd->balls_left);
  mvprintw(0, 52, "Score: %u", gd->score);
  if(!gd->running)
  {
    attron(A_BLINK);
    if(gd->balls_left)
      mvprintw(0, 16, "PRESS LEFT OR RIGHT TO START");
    else
      mvprintw(0, 25, "GAME OVER");
    attroff(A_BLINK);
  }                 

  mvaddch(1, 0, ACS_ULCORNER);
  mvaddch(1, 79, ACS_URCORNER);
  for(int y = 2; y < 24; y++)
  {
    mvaddch(y, 0, ACS_VLINE);
    mvaddch(y, 79, ACS_VLINE);
  }
  for(int x = 1; x < 79; x++)
    mvaddch(1, x, ACS_HLINE);

  const int y_offset = 2;
  const int x_offset = 1;

  for(int y = 0; y < board_y_size; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < board_x_size; x++)
    {
      chtype char_to_print;
      switch(gd->board[y][x])
      {
      case EMPTY:
        char_to_print = ' ';
        break;
      case BRICK:
        char_to_print = ACS_CKBOARD | COLOR_PAIR(brick_color);
        break;
      case BALL:
        char_to_print = 'O';
        break;
      }
      mvaddch(y+y_offset, x+x_offset, char_to_print);
    }

  const int racket_print_pos = gd->racket_pos+x_offset;
  mvaddch(23, racket_print_pos-1, ACS_HLINE);
  mvaddch(23, racket_print_pos, ACS_TTEE);
  mvaddch(23, racket_print_pos+1, ACS_HLINE);

  refresh();
}

void game_loop(game_data* gd)
{
  int sleep_time;
  bool advance_lv = true;

  while(true)
  { 
    if(!gd->running)
    {
      nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
      if(gd->balls_left)
        if(advance_lv)
          init_new_level(gd);
        else
          recover_from_miss(gd);
      print_game_data(gd);
      int input;
      do input = getch();
      while(!(gd->balls_left && (input == KEY_LEFT || input == KEY_RIGHT)));
      sleep_time = start_level(gd, input);
      nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
      process_turn(gd);
    }
    else
    {
      print_game_data(gd);
      napms(sleep_time);
      int racket_move = 0;
      int input;
      while((input = getch()) != ERR)
        if(input == KEY_LEFT)
          racket_move = -1;
        else if(input == KEY_RIGHT)
          racket_move = 1;
        else if(input == KEY_DOWN)
          racket_move = 0;
      move_racket(gd, racket_move);
      advance_lv = process_turn(gd);
    }
  }
}

void cleanup(int signal)
{
  endwin();
  exit(0);
}

int main()
{
  struct sigaction cleanup_action = { .sa_handler = cleanup, .sa_flags = 0 };
  sigfillset(&cleanup_action.sa_mask);
  sigaction(SIGINT, &cleanup_action, NULL);
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  noecho();
  nonl();
  curs_set(0);
  start_color();
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

  init_pair(brick_color, COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE);
  init_pair(other_color, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);

  attrset(COLOR_PAIR(other_color));

  game_data gd = {.lv = 0, .balls_left = 3, .score = 0};
  game_loop(&gd);

  return 0;
}
```

I did spot two flaws in my code (DRY violations) and hopefully corrected them before posting it here - so I did take time to make it (reasonably) clean. Still, I'm sure the code is not ideal - what are the flaws I did not spot? (the game seems to be working)

There is still one flaw I'm aware of but that I consciously chose not to fix - namely, I'm not checking if the functions I call do not return errors. However, I think that error-checking in C is so tedious and the probability that these calls return errors is so low on any 'reasonable' platform that I thought it was simply not practical to do error-checking: the benefits would not justify cluttering the code.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Could you add some context or description about your code?

Comment: @dfhwze This is the context: On an Internet forum a person came with their homework, to write Arkanoid in a console - it seemed they wanted someone to do their homework for them so I did not respond. However, I found the task interesting, especially when I broadened the scope of the assignment - so I wrote such arkanoid for my own entertainment. However, I don't really know C coding patterns so I'd be interested to know what more exprienced devs think about my code. This is kind of the whole context

Comment: @dfhwze edited Q....

Comment: You might want to fix your `SIGINT` handler to not call `exit` but instead [raise `SIGINT` anew](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html).  This improves the behaviour when your program is called from a script or similar and is just good programming style.

Comment: For those of us who don't know the game, can you summarise it for us?  I see `enum { EMPTY, BRICK, BALL }` and wonder if it's a Breakout-style game?

Comment: @TobySpeight The way I understand terminology "breakout" and "arkanoid" are synonymous.

Comment: Thanks @gaazkam - that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Enable more compiler warnings.  With `gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion` I see, amongst others:

```
222224.c: In function ‘recover_from_miss’:
222224.c:57:1: warning: label ‘ball_found’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 ball_found:
 ^~~~~~~~~~
222224.c: In function ‘cleanup’:
222224.c:331:18: warning: unused parameter ‘signal’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void cleanup(int signal)
              ~~~~^~~~~~
222224.c: At top level:
222224.c:337:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int main()
     ^~~~
222224.c: In function ‘main’:
222224.c:339:10: error: variable ‘cleanup_action’ has initializer but incomplete type
   struct sigaction cleanup_action = { .sa_handler = cleanup, .sa_flags = 0 };
          ^~~~~~~~~
```

Fixing these would immediately improve the program.  (That last one requires us to set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to an appropriate value before including `<signal.h>`; that's easiest done as a command-line argument such as `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `-D_GNU_SOURCE`).

Please use `ALL_CAPS` for macros.  Macros need to be immediately recognisable so that we can treat them with extra caution, as they don't act like variables.

There's a lot of naked constants sprinkled over the code.  For example,

> ```
> gd->racket_pos = 39;
> ```

Is it coincidental that this is `board_x_size / 2`?  Or is it intrinsically related?

And:

> ```
>   if(gd->lv % 3 == 0)
>     gd->balls_left++;
> ```

That's baking the game's parameters into its code; a more flexible game would allow such things to be set up as gameplay configuration.

We could do with some targeted comments to help readers (including future-you) to understand what values mean.  For example, we have:

> ```
> int start_level(game_data* gd, int input)
> {
>     /* ... */
>     return (int)round(1000.0/pow(1.25, gd->lv-1));
> }
> ```

It's not obvious why `start_level()` should even return a value, and completely opaque as to what the value might mean.  I had to find the calling code to discover that it's a time delay, and then look up the documentation of `napms()` to discover the units.  I'd argue that would be better obtained by a separate function, e.g.

```
int millis_per_frame(const game_data *game);
```

That immediately documents what it does, rather than hiding in a return value from an unrelated function.